# Raspberry Pi - Trouble playing local video files in browser (Midori, Epiphany)

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, html5-video, midori, epiphany

I've stumbled upon this problem, while coding my project.
I have this html that plays a video:

```
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="/videos/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Unfortuanately it is not starting the video.

However if i set the source of the video to be taken from the web (e.x.) http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4
It plays the video correctly. Does anybody know what could be a trouble in here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<video width="720" controls autoplay loop>
  <source src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```